# Vision and ARKit frameworks in Xcode project

Tags: swift, machine-learning, augmented-reality, arkit, apple-vision

I want to create an ARKit app using Xcode. I want it to recognize a generic rectangle without pressing a button and that subsequently the rectangle does a certain function.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `ARKit` to recognise rectangles, only `Vision`.

In case to recognise generic rectangles, use `VNDetectRectanglesRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

As you rightly wrote, you need to use `Vision` or `CoreML` frameworks in your project along with ARKit. Also you have to create a pre-trained machine learning model (`.mlmodel` file) to classify input data to recognize your generic rectangle.

For creating a learning model use one of the following resources: [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org), [Turi](https://turi.com), [Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org), or [Keras](https://keras.io).

Using `.mlmodel` with **classification tags** inside it, Vision requests return results as `VNRecognizedObjectObservation` objects, which identify objects found in the captured scene. So, if the image's corresponding tag is available via recognition process in ARSKView then an `ARAnchor` will be created (and `SK`/`SCN` object can be placed onto this `ARAnchor`).

Here's a snippet code on a topic "how it works":

```
import UIKit
import ARKit
import Vision
import SpriteKit

.................................................................

// file – ARBridge.swift
class ARBridge {
    static let shared = ARBridge()
    var anchorsToIdentifiers = [ARAnchor : String]()
}

.................................................................

// file – Scene.swift
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    do {
        let model = try VNCoreMLModel(for: Inceptionv3().model)
        let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model, completionHandler: { (request, error) in

             DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 guard let results = request.results as? [VNClassificationObservation], let result = results.first else {
                     print ("No results.")
                     return
                 }
                 var translation = matrix_identity_float4x4
                 translation.columns.3.z = -0.75
                 let transform = simd_mul(currentFrame.camera.transform, translation)
                 let anchor = ARAnchor(transform: transform)
                 ARBridge.shared.anchorsToIdentifiers[anchor] = result.identifier
                 sceneView.session.add(anchor: anchor)
             }
         }
         let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: currentFrame.capturedImage, options: [:])
         try handler.perform([request])
     } catch { 
         print(error) 
     }
}

.................................................................

// file – ViewController.swift
func view(_ view: ARSKView, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SKNode? {
    guard let identifier = ARBridge.shared.anchorsToIdentifiers[anchor] else {
        return nil
    }
    let labelNode = SKLabelNode(text: identifier)
    labelNode.horizontalAlignmentMode = .center
    labelNode.verticalAlignmentMode = .center
    labelNode.fontName = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 24).fontName
    return labelNode
}
```

> And you can download two Apple's projects (**sample code**) written by Vision engineers:

[Recognizing Objects in Live Capture](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/recognizing_objects_in_live_capture)

[Classifying Images with Vision and Core ML](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/classifying_images_with_vision_and_core_ml)

Hope this helps.